# AngularJS: How to create a model which holds an array for a dynamic list of input fields?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have quite an interesting question (I hope) for all you AngularJS gurus out there. I am looking to create a dynamic list of form input fields based on a SELECT dropdown. As an example, we have a number of categories with each category having a set of specifications which are unique to that category. To help with the explanation we have the following:

Firstly, in the controller we start by initializing the models.

```
$scope.category = {};
$scope.category.specs = [];
```

Next we ready the data to be used in the form (actually retrieved from the server via $http). We also initialize a variable to the first element in the categories array.

```
$scope.categories = [
  { "id": "1", "name": "mobile", specs: [ 
    { "id": "1", "label": "Operating System" }, 
    { "id": "2", "label": "Camera type" } ] },
  { "id": "2", "name": "laptop", specs: [ 
    { "id": "1", "label": "Operating System" },
    { "id": "2", "label": "Graphics Card" } ] }
};  
$scope.selectedCategory = $scope.categories[0];
```

In the form, we have a dropdown which when selected loads the appropriate input fields specific to that category. We use the ngRepeat directive to accomplish this. This is a dynamic list of fields based on $scope.categories.specs. (please note the ???)

```
<select ng-model="selectedCategory" ng-options="category.name for category in categories"></select>

<div ng-repeat="spec in selectedCategory.specs">
  <label>{{spec.label}}</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="???">
</div>
```

Ultimately, when the user clicks the submit button, we would like to extract the category he/she has selected and then package it together with the specifications they have filled in.  The post request should contain something like the following for instance (of course, I only included one spec item, but in reality there would be many):

```
{ "id": "1", specs [ { "id": "2", "details": "RADEON HD 8970M" } ] }
```

Unfortunately I am not really sure how to accomplish this. I need to somehow create an array for the spec model, and then ensure that both the ID and user entered data are appropriately extracted... what goes in the ??? and what do we do after? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller, initialize `$scope.specDetails` as follows:

```
$scope.specDetails = {};
angular.forEach($scope.categories, function (category, index1) {
    $scope.specDetails[category.id] = {};
    angular.forEach(category.specs, function (spec, index2) {
        $scope.specDetails[category.id][spec.id] = '';
    });
});
```

In the html, replace "???" with `specDetails[selectedCategory.id][spec.id]`

Answer (score 1):

this is how I do it.  I make a form, validate it with angular, and then when its valid I submit it with a function.

```
  <form name="signup_form" novalidate ng-submit="signupForm()"></form>


  $scope.signupForm = function() {
var data = $scope.signup;
$http({
  method  : 'POST',
  url     : 'http://yoursite.com/mail.php',
    data    : $.param(data), // pass in data as strings
    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
  })
.success(function(data) {

});
}
```

also if you want to look at another form validation system for angular check out http://nimbly.github.io/angular-formly/#!/   It may help you solve your current form system.